# COD Black Ops: Can opponents voice chat in free for all?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In a free for all match, can I voice chat with my opponents?

One of my friends started playing Black Ops (it's her first FPS game ever) and to teach her how to play I created a private free for all match so we would be the only two players on the map.

I tried voice chat with her and everything was set up correctly (we could see the speaker icon above our heads blink when either of us spoke in the map).

Only thing is I could not hear her at all (the volume was up high).

I know in TDM you can't listen to the enemy chatter due to strategy and stuff but I would guess you could listen to enemies in free for all (for trash talking).

Anyway, to repeat, is it possible to listen to enemy voice chat in FFA?

Comment: Female + voice chat + CoD = chaos. Just a fair warning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Free for All, all chat is enabled. You should be able to talk to any player in the match.

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine. I once played 1v1 against a friend on Nuketown. It was a free for all or team deathmatch, I don't remember, but we could hear each other very clearly.